# SFML: улавливание кириллицы в TextEntered

Tags: c++, sfml

Если использовать код из официальной документации SFML

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
{
    if (event.text.unicode < 128) //Если убрать "< 128", то всё равно вместо кириллицы будут знаки вопроса.
        std::cout << "ASCII character typed: " << static_cast<char>(event.text.unicode) << std::endl;
}
```

то программа улавливает только латинские символы. Наряду с ней мне нужна кириллица, но я не знаю, как это реализовать...

(Помимо этого хотелось бы найти решение, чтобы было возможно копирование из/в буфер обмена сочетаниями клавиш CTRL+C, CTRL+V)

Comment: `std::cout` не поддерживает кирилицу. Если кроссплатформенность не важна - `wcout` в помощь. А если важна, то используйте Qt

Comment: дело даже не в cout, а в том, что возвращает event.text.unicode

Comment: так, беру свои слова назад. Если сделать так: 'text.setString(event.text.unicode)', то даже русские символы отображаются корректно... Но почему при обычной передаче 'text.setString("Текст")' нужно добавлять префикс L? В некоторых ситуациях мне нужно передать в setString() обычную переменную типа string, а к ней этот  префикс я не приставлю...

Comment: обычная переменная типа string не особо рассчитана на что-то кроме ascii. Для буфера обмена на windows обязателен двухбайтовый wchar_t и L